# How to get the return value of the Jquery.ajax succes function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like this

```
function doSomething(){
      Jquery.ajax(type: "POST",
                url: "HelloWorld",
                 success: function (msg) {
                 if(msg.d =="Hello World")
                 {
                     return true;
                 }else
                  {
                     return false;
                  }
                 }

      );
}
```

i want to know something based on which the return value of the succes function.
Can somebody help?

Comment: You mean the return value of the function that is called upon success, or the return value that causes that function to be called (or not).

Comment: i mean the return value of the success function

Comment: I did not understand your question very well.

Comment: The Jquey.ajax on success function returns some value how can i get that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is **Asynchronous**.

The callback function will run when the HTTP request comes back, by which time `doSomething` will have finished executing.

Whatever you want to happen in response to the HTTP response returning has to be done in the callback function and not in whatever called it.

Comment: Not that I would recommend that, but what if you would set "async" to "false" in the JQuery.ajax call?

Comment: Is so problematic that it is not worth considering.

Comment: is there a way in which i can get the msg from the service in the function doSomething

Comment: No there isn't. Whatever you want to happen in response to the HTTP response returning has to be done in the callback function and not in whatever called it.

Comment: I figured out a way to do that.    msg=Jquery.ajax{...}.resposeText; and set async:false

Comment: Everytime you use async: false, your user experience goes down the toilet and God does this to a puppy: http://www.umtss.org.uk/caption_comp/captionpics/100926.jpg

Comment: I am not sure if that is even true?  I had a jquery function in an MVC project I wrote that called a method and the return value was json.  I used the return value of that method to populate a table?  Are you sure that can't happen?