# Retrieve data from $.ajax function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have used $.ajax function to fetch data from C# in asp.net MVC3.0, Now I want is to get the value from the success function of $.ajax and used it in another function defining global variable and putting the result in it is not working so please let me know how can I get the value.

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: Is it something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562696/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-the-jquery-ajax-succes-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke a callback function from within the `success` function. Most likely you are treating everything as synchronous when infact Ajax is asynchronous.

Low down dirty way would probably be to specify `async:false`

Comment: Is there any sample code that would be much easier for me. After return statement how to retrieve the value in another function